# Implementing a reusable tabbed component using Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I'm trying to implement a tabbed reusable `component` in `vueJs` but I'm getting an error that a particular component is not defined. Below are both components

```
//TabComponent
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-xl-12">
                <div class="card-box">
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-bordered">
                        <li v-for="tab in tabs" :key="tab" class="nav-item">
                            <a href="javascript:;"  @click="selectedComponent = tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false"  :class="['nav-link', { active: selectedComponent === tab }]"> {{tab}} </a>
                        </li> 
                    </ul>
                    <div class="tab-content">
                        <component :is="selectedComponent"></component>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'TabComponent',
    props: [ selectedComponent, tabs ] //The error is coming from this line
}
</script>
```

I have imported it to this component and currently it shows the error 
`Uncaught ReferenceError: selectedComponent is not defined`

```
//Entitlements component
<template>
    <div>
        <tab-component :tabs="tabs" :selectedComponent="selectedComponent" />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import TabComponent from "../../../components/TabComponent";
import List from "./Entitlements/List";
import MyEntitlements from "./Entitlements/MyEntitlements";
export default {
    name: 'Entitlements',

    components: {List, MyEntitlements, TabComponent},

    data(){
        return{
            tabs: ['List', 'MyEntitlements'],
            selectedComponent: 'List',
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: remove the quotes from `'List'`?

Comment: Same error @depperm

Comment: add `.vue` to the import line

Comment: same error... The error is from the `TabComponent`

Comment: see about setting the default value of `selectedComponent` [doc](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html)

Answer (score 0):

> HTML attribute names are case-insensitive, so browsers will interpret
> any uppercase characters as lowercase. That means when you’re using
> in-DOM templates, camelCased prop names need to use their kebab-cased
> (hyphen-delimited) equivalents ([source](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Prop-Casing-camelCase-vs-kebab-case))

Try with:

```html
<tab-component :tabs="tabs" :selected-component="selectedComponent" />
```

---

**Edit**:

If you define props as an array, change the list with strings (see "Prop types" [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Prop-Types)):

```js
props: [ 'selectedComponent', 'tabs' ]
```